# NSURLConnection FTP file upload

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-upload, ftp, nsurlconnection

I am trying to upload a PNG file on FTP server using the following code.

```
NSURL *ftpURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://username:password@localhost"];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:ftpURL];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imageUrl\"; filename=\"dummy.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
NSMutableData *postData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSData *data=UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
[postData appendData:data];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

I don't receive any NSURL connection,like it has failed or ask for Authentication. Only, call back I receive is of

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

I am not sure whether NSURLConnection supports ftp upload. I am not looking to implement it using CFFTPStream. Can any one correct me in my approach?

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: @Otium The link you mentioned uses CFFTPStream, but I want it to be done it using NSURLConnection if possible.

Comment: @andyPaul: Did you ever complete this ? I am also looking to upload images to FTP server using NSURLConnection. I have used CFFTPStream though, but want to try NSURLConnection now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to use FTP and POST in one go, which won't work in almost any case.

FTP is a complete different protocoll, see for example http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html

It is somewhat more interactive, however many ftp server have a http wrapper which allows easy download, but upload will remain special. So if you want to use it, you should take a library or CFFTPStream.

Comment: I am using HTTP for FTP upload. So, is it possible to use pure FTP upload using NSURLConnection.

Comment: @andyPaul: Cool, I did not succeed and you are targeting an ordinary FTP server,  do you have a sample code?

Comment: The code I used is in the question that I have asked. The FTP server is a local ftp server on my machine.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try on an external ftp server and check it again.

Comment: Ok, now I have some results. Overall funny, I tried two different ftp servers. Both allow the connection and more or less ignore the post attachment. One was confused, but the other replied with a directory listing (mime type application/x-ftp-directory) as expected.  So I am sorry, there doesn't seems to be a simple shortcut to bypass the ordinary read and write stream handling of the FTP protocol. However, reading files seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I've had good success with [BlackRacoon](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon).

Comment: Even this uses CFFTPStream. I am looking it to implement it using NSURLConnection.

Comment: I'm curious why the implementation matters. I would think all that matters is that your app can complete the FTP transfer.

Answer (score 2):

Uploading file over FTP will require using FTP commands like STOR or APPE. And FTP commands are not possible using NSURLConnection because NSURLConnection does not provide any way to send FTP commands.  To do that, you'll have to use CFFTPStream.

The SimpleFTPSample sample code shows this.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/

Specifically, it shows download (via NSURLConnection and CFFTPStream), upload, directory listing, and directory creation (all via CFFTPStream).

Note: CFFTPStream has no public API for deleting files , although it is possible to delete files using the deprecated, but still functional, CFURLDestroyResource.

There is currently no way to send arbitrary FTP commands via CFFTPStream.  If you need to do that, you'll have to create (or acquire) your own FTP library.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, Thanks.